# karma +typescript + SystemJS -- cache problems

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

Config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],
        files: [ /*all from jspm*/],
        plugins: [
            "karma-jspm",
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-chrome-launcher'
        ],
        jspm: {
            loadFiles: ['src/*.ts'], // here my tests are located
            packages: "jspm/"
        },
        proxies: {
            '/src/': '/base/src/',      //to simplify /base url 
            '/jspm/': '/base/jspm/'
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

For example in "src" directory we have `test1.ts` with test  `... expect(true).toBe(false) ...`

Karma starts and show that test is fail, OK

Then i FIX test `... expect(true).toBe(true) ...`

Karma execute tests (so it watch changes), but... test still fail.
When I open Chrome at 9876 i see that it loads 'test1.ts' and 'test1.ts!trsnpiled' by XHR  (system.js works) but it's content is still unchanged, status of response - 200 (not 304), neither "disable cache" nor "Clean browser cache" don't  helps.

I look at headers : Date changed
initially it was Date:Tue, 01 Dec 2015 09:51:26 GMT
and then Date:Tue, 01 Dec 2015 09:53:40 GMT
(strange but mimetype for *.ts is video/mp2v while it's not for this issue)

But content - not - it's still old.

Before i used typescript-preprocessor and native Karma module loader and where's not such problems but with system.js loader it occured, and i don't know who is responsible.

Then i restart karma it tests well.

Answer (score 0):

Have fix both problems (invalid mime and caching) 
in karma (mime) and karma-jspm (caching) source code, 
pull requests made to these teams - if someone has same problems - 
can look at

https://github.com/Workiva/karma-jspm/pull/115

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/pull/1736